# Why won't createNativeQuery return records containing null value?

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have two identical Symfony 2.8 projects. The only difference in these two projects is that one is running Doctrine ORM version `v2.4.8` and the other is running `v2.5.5`

**The problem**

I have this following piece of code in both Symfony projects.

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('EntityBundle:New', 'u');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'newPK', 'newPK');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'msg', 'msg');
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('StoredProcedureName @a= :a, @b= :b, @c= :c', $rsm);
$query->setParameter('a', 'a');
$query->setParameter('b', 'b');
$query->setParameter('c', 'c');
$result = $query->getArrayResult();
var_dump($result);
```

My Entity looks like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * New
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="dbo.New")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class New
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="newPK", type="string", length=255, unique=false)
     */
    private $newPK;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="msg", type="string", length=255, unique=false)
     */
    private $msg;
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNewPK()
    {
        return $this->newPK;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $newPK
     */
    public function setNewPK($newPK)
    {
        $this->newPK = $newPK;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMsg()
    {
        return $this->msg;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $msg
     */
    public function setMsg($msg)
    {
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }
}
```

In my StoredProcedure all I have is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedureName] 
AS
SELECT null as newPK, 'aaa' As msg
GO
```

This code works perfectly fine on version `v2.4.8` returning me null value perfectly. However this doesn't work on `v2.5.5`. All it returns is an array with NULL inside it and not the `newPK` AND `msg` value. If I remove the null and replace it with an empty string or anything else for that matter, it works. But for some god forsaken reason, it does not like the `NULL` value. All I want is to check if null is returned or not but I can't seem to check without doctrine returning me proper values.

Is there anything that changed between these versions that I am not aware of? What do I need to do in order to read `NULL` values from a native query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a work around with this one using `addScalarResult` instead of `addFieldResult`. The modified code looks like this:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('u', 'newPK', 'newPK');
$rsm->addScalarResult('u', 'msg', 'msg');
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('StoredProcedureName @a= :a, @b= :b, @c= :c', $rsm);
$query->setParameter('a', 'a');
$query->setParameter('b', 'b');
$query->setParameter('c', 'c');
$result = $query->getArrayResult();
var_dump($result);
```